# Is there any way or algorithm to generate unique random numbers without store?

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, random

I wanna create unique random numbers with size of `m` and range of 0 to `n-1`. I think there are 2 traditional ways to do this as below.

```kotlin
val m = 100
val n = 1000
val set = mutableSetOf<Int>()

while (set.size < m) {
    val v = Random.nextInt(n)
    set.add(v)
}
```

```kotlin
val m = 100
val n = 1000
val set = (0..n).shuffled().subList(0, m).toSet()
```

Both are good ways to get unique random numbers, but they need some storage to check if numbers are unique or not.

However, I need to generate unique random numbers without any space, because the `m` or `n` would be quite big(e.g. a billion). And note that the generated numbers do not have to be same every time the code is executed.(like `Random` with seed). Is there any algorithm for this ?

Comment: Do you need them in random order? I.e., if you can accept ascending order, then you could get the next random integer based only on the current range (last int + 1 up to max int), and the number of picks remaining.

Comment: I like Dave’s idea. Other than that I think you’d at least need to store the previous ones.

Comment: Thank you for your idea, but I need random order.

Comment: A [linear congruential generator (LCG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) with modulus `m` is one possible option. But there are two problems. First is picking a **multiplier** and **increment** that work well with the chosen modulus (i.e. produce a LCG with period `m`). Second is that LCGs in general are not very good. Specifically, the least significant bits (LSBs) are fairly predictable. You can hide that problem somewhat by rearranging the bits, so that the LSBs are not adjacent, and near the middle of the numbers.

Comment: I have an approach, but it will be complicated and slow.  But you get random numbers, random order, no obvious biases, no storage.

Comment: @btilly Sounds interesting. I, for one, would like to see that. Will it generate integers in a specified range?

Comment: @user3386109 Absolutely.  In the specified range, in no apparent order.

Comment: Suppose we go with my first comment, generate in sorted order, but then reverse the digits? Here's a sample of 10 ints generated this way: 62055606,
 50932358,
 93094831,
 192349351,
 431396851,
 842679795,
 455375686,
 378952847,
 138031159,
 351818979. Would this work for you? Instead of strictly reversing the digits, you could pick any fixed permutation which leaves the first digit somewhere in the middle, to make it even less apparent what's going on.

Comment: @user3386109 I have posted my answer.  It uses MD5 hashing for a random number generator that depends on decisions made. I use this to separate out inputs and outputs in such a way that choices are deterministic and consistent.

Comment: @btilly You delivered exactly as promised ;) (even if it is completely impractical).

Comment: @user3386109 Exactly as promised, including the promise of being slow!

Comment: Are you sure you got it right in the example? How with n=100 you could get m=1000 UNIQUE numbers? Did you messed up n and m?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux You right, I made a mistake. I edited the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First observation. An MD5 hash is a 128 bit number.  Dividing `2^128` by this therefore gives a number in the range 0 to 1.

If we use an MD5 hash as a random number, use that to make a `decision`, and then MD5 hash `decision + hash`, we'll get another random number.  Therefore you can write a program that makes a set of decisions off of random information.  Any time you make the same sequence of decisions, the same random numbers will come up.  But once any decision changes, the random numbers will change thereafter.

Using this we can write a function allowing us to make a random choice from a binomial distribution:

```
count = binomial_choices_before(seed, n, m, k)
```

This function will answer the question, "We chose `m` distinct numbers out of the range `0..n-1`. How many are before `k`?"  Internally it will need to make a series of decisions, replacing the `seed`, but the caller will still have the original `seed`.  I will leave details of that function to the reader.  (You probably want to use a normal approximation to get into a range, then more exact calculations from there.  But, play around with it.  It is enough for me that it is doable.)

So how is the overall random choice going to work?  We will start with the following information:

```
seed = random information
n    = range 0..n-1
m    = how many will be chosen
i    = we're choosing the i'th of m
```

First we use `binomial_choices_before` to figure out how many of those `m` are in the range `0..(n//2 - 1)`.  (I'm using `//` as notation for integer division.)  Call that `m1`.

Use that fact as a decision to modify the `seed` and generate another random number.

Next we will figure out which side we will go on, and how many went on that side before us.  For now, assume we can, and I'll give details of how later.  We will **NOT** use this decision process to modify the `seed`.

We've now figured out that our number is in a smaller range of size around `n/2`.  We know how many other choices are in that range, and it is probably around `m/2`.  We know where we are among those choices, and it is probably around `i/2`.  We can proceed recursively until we are in a range with one thing.  We then make a final random choice of which one, and that is our answer.

---

Now let's explain how we figure out which choice we make, and where we are in the list of choices that we made.  (Those two are intertwined.)

We'll do this in a separate function.  So we can mangle the `seed` all we want, and not affect the larger decision flow.

First we modify the `seed` with the knowledge that we're trying to figure out how many of the `m1` that went on the first side do so out of the first `m//2`.  (So this is a different random number than we produce elsewhere in the decision process.)

Next, we produce that answer.  Again, we're doing it using `binomial_choices_before`.

Now we know if `i` is in the first half of the choices, or the second.  If in the first half of choices, we have put `i` in a smaller population of choices.  If in the second half of choices, we know how many of the first `m//2` went on each side, and we STILL have put `i` in a smaller population of choices.

We then recursively go into our half of the choices until we figure out how many of the first `i-1` choices went into the first range of numbers, and also how many of the first `i` did.  If those are the same, we went into the second range, and we know how many did before.  If they are different, we went into the first range, and we know how many did before.  Either way we have our answer.

**NOTE** Suppose that we run this twice, for different numbers `i` and `j`.  For as far in the decision tree as `i` and `j` remain in the same group, they will make all the same decisions, generate all the same `seed` values, and come to all the same conclusions.  Once we split them into separate ranges, each will modify its seed, and then on make uncorrelated decisions that cannot come into conflict.

---

The result is an entirely deterministic, but unpredictable, function that takes `seed, n, m, i` and uses `seed` to produce the `i`th number in the choice of `m` out of `n` in such a way that the numbers will be produced in random order, and the same number will not be produced twice.

Why does this work?  We have random numbers that are tied to a chain of decisions.  Any two numbers that will be output close to each other will make a sequence of the same decisions, generating the same random numbers, until they are in separate ranges.  And any two inputs that are close to each other whose outputs are also close to each other will make the same decisions about where they are within the range of inputs going to this output range, until their input or output ranges are separated.  Therefore we can guarantee that if a particular input went to a particular output, no other input went to that output.

---

Unfortunately this procedure requires a ton of MD5 hashing.  So it will be slow. But it is embarrassingly parallel.

If you stick an LRU cache in front of a lot of the logic, you can skip a lot of the repeated logic to speed it up.  How much it speeds up depends on how much caching you do.  But it still will be slow. :-(

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Oops, good point.  Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Encryption is a one-to-one mapping, so unique inputs are guaranteed to produce unique outputs. You can encrypt the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, ... and produce unique outputs provided you keep the same key. All you have to do is keep track of the key you are using and where you have got to in the input sequence.

You will need to do some work to ensure that the output falls in the required range. An AES block is 128 bits, which makes 128, 256, 512 bit outputs simple. Otherwise you will have to use some form of format preserving encryption to get the output within range.

Comment: The "format preserving encryption" bit sounds hard. If the range of possible outputs has more than the range values, how can you reduce the range without creating the potential for collisions?  If it has less than the range values, the hard part is still ahead.

Comment: Great idea, but totally impractical. There's no way to change the output range without losing the uniqueness guarantee.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Not sure what you mean, the whole point of [format-preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) is to efficiently create a cryptographic permutation of an arbitrary sequence of integers.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Wow. I didn't know that was a thing.  Yeah, that makes it a question of just using a format preserving encryption to turn the range `0..n-1` back into the range `0..n-1` in random order.  Then only call it with numbers from `0..m-1`.

Comment: If you need, say, a 700 bit number, you can pad the input number with leading 0 bits to get 700 / 128 rounded up to 6 blocks in the input to give you six blocks output. If the number is not in range, then you can use cycle walking to get a number within the required range. See [Format Preserving Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption).

Answer (score 0):

Well, good way to go is to try [Reservoir Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling). Basically, sample m items from large set of n items.

Don't know much of a Kotlin, code below is Python, adapted to [0...n) ranges from [1...n] used in the wiki

```
import numpy as np

def ReservoirSample(n: int, m: int, rng):
    '''Sample m items from 0...n-1 sequence using Reservoir Sampling'''

    R = np.empty(m, dtype=np.int32)
    for i in range(0, m):  # fill the reservoir array
        R[i] = i

    W = np.exp(np.log(1.0 - rng.random())/m) # 1.0 - rng.random() to make (0...1] range

    while i < n:
        i = i + np.floor(np.log(1.0 - rng.random())/np.log(1.0 - W))
        if i < n:
            # replace a random item of the reservoir with item i
            idx = rng.integers(low=0, high=m) # random index in the range [0...m)
            R[idx] = i
            W = W * np.exp(np.log(1.0 - rng.random())/m)

    return R


rngen = np.random.default_rng(12345)

q = ReservoirSample(1000, 100, rngen)
```